# validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [EnvironmentVariables]]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I got this error in our AWS pipeline, after making some changes to our CodeBuild template.

```
    EnvironmentVariables:
    -  Name: MY_PIPELINE
       Type: PLAINTEXT
       Value: !Sub '${foo}-${bar}'
```

I am not sure what the problem is, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had not indented it properly. `EnvironmentVariables` should have been a child of `Environment`, instead it was a sibling and a child of `/`, which is what the error was saying as well - `unsupported properties in {/}: [EnvironmentVariables]]`.